# Examples of balancing distribution of class responsibilities in object-oriented model

Tags: oop, object-oriented-analysis

In "The Unified Modelling Language User's Guide" by Bochs et. al. there is in 'Chapter 4. Classes' there (sub)section titled *"Modeling the **Distribution of Responsibilities** in a System"*.  It talks about balancing responsibilities, which can lead to splitting or coalescing of classes.

Could you give me example how such "**balancing of responsibilities**" might look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think "balancing of responsibilities" happens when classes are neither too small nor too large. If responsibilities are not well balanced, then the object model has a few large classes that have too many responsibilities. Or even worse, there is a single object that does all the work. This is sometimes called the "God object". It is considered an anti-pattern. Google "god object".

A related consequence of having a God object is having many small classes that do very little other than encapsulate data. When responsibilities are well balanced, every class has a set of well-defined services and holds just enough attributes and methods to fulfill those responsibilities.

Wikipedia refers to well-balanced responsibilities as "ravioli code", but I had never heard that term used before.